# How do I update my EditText of a fragment from another fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I have two fragments, in which on first fragment there is 5 edittext box and in second fragment there is 3 edittext box and one button . On clicking of fragment two button , I want to generate alert message on 5 edittext box which are in first fragment .

Can anyone help how can i achieve this ??

Early reply is appreciable

Comment: Have you try anything?

Comment: You can get the second fragment by tag using fragment manager, and then do whatever you want to its views.
be careful of NPEs though.

Comment: No, not yet . I am a beginner in android . I am handling the data between both  fragment but i don't know how to implement this !!

Comment: Like this:
SecondFragment fragment = (SecondFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);

Comment: hi @murtadhaalsabbagh thanks for your quick reply ,can you show me any example . That make the things more clear for me

Comment: You can alternatively use the shared preference to update the edittext

Comment: NICK, I did below, you can check it and tell me if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the second fragment by tag using fragment manager, and then do whatever you want to its views. be careful of NPEs though.

First, when you call the second fragment you should set a tag:

```
SecondFragment fragment = SecondFragment.newInstance();
getActivity()
        .getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragments_container, fragment, "second_fragment_tag")
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

Then, you can access it from the first fragment using the following:

```
SecondFragment fragment = (SecondFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("second_fragment_tag");
```